# Integrating Appboy Feedback Fragment

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement the Appboy Feedback Fragment into my Android Application and I'm running into so difficulty. I create the Fragment like this:

```
AppboyFeedbackFragment appboyFeedbackFragment = new AppboyFeedbackFragment();
```

And when I want to add it to the current Activity I do it like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.settingsParent, appboyFeedbackFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

But when I do this it tells me appboyFeedbackFragment is not a Fragment. Next I tried casting it to a Fragment since it extends the Fragment class, however that did not work either. I'm not sure how to add the Fragment. I'm new to fragments, so I might be misunderstanding something. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi shadowarcher - I think that you're probably using default Android fragments while the AppboyFeedbackFragment comes from the Support v4 library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did :

```
public class SendFeedbackActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_feedback_layout);

        final FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();

        AppboyFeedbackFragment appboyFeedbackFragment = (AppboyFeedbackFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.feedback_fragment);
        appboyFeedbackFragment.setFeedbackFinishedListener(new AppboyFeedbackFragment.FeedbackFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeedbackFinished() {
                // Pops the top of the back stack and displays the previous fragment
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The content of send_feedback_layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/feedback_fragment"
    android:name="com.appboy.ui.AppboyFeedbackFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```